# How do I compile Go from sources if I received the building_Go_requires_Go_1_17_13_or_later error?

Tags: go, compilation, dependencies, bootstrapping

I tried to compile Go using an existing version of Go, but I was given this error message?.

What does this mean if I want to compile Go from source? The last version of go that could be compiled with C was the 1.4 release, but now I need version 1.17.13?

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Here are some of the documents I have read while trying to resolve this :) https://go.dev/doc/go1.20#bootstrap ; https://go.dev/doc/install/source

Comment: Install a supported version (latest).

Comment: What does install mean in this context? Installing is the end goal, but I am encountering a problem while attempting to build from source.

Comment: Install the latest version of the Go compiler. And if you need more help: provide much more details.

Comment: [1/2] I do not quite parse the question. Until, and including v1.4, Go was written in C, and since 1.5 onwards Go is written in Go. I do not know (and lazy to research) whether the now-latest stable 1.21 is still buildable with 1.4 (I would not expect that, actually), but if it's true, _and_ you for some reason want to bootstrap the latest Go from the C sources of Go ≤ 1.4, then you will need to chase the chain of versions: like use 1.4 to build 1.X, X > 4 and so on until you can build the latest stable one.

Comment: [2/2] if you need to build, say, the tip of the `master` branch of the Go source code, then just grab the latest stable precompiled Go from <https://go.dev/dl/> and use it to build what you need.

Comment: While we're at it, [the language is called Go](https://go.dev/doc/faq#go_or_golang) (the logic is roughly the same you do not say Javalang, Pythonlang and so on).

Comment: The switch of the boostrap process to Go 1.17 has happened during the 1.20 release cycle: <https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44505>. Hence, Go 1.19 should still be buildable with Go 1.4, and if you're after bootstrapping from C, then the simplest approach appears to be building 1.17 using 1.4, and then building 1.21 using 1.17.

Comment: @kostix and also, it appears the plan is to extend that chain by another bounce each year, according to this quote from the bootstrap: " Go 1.22 will require the final point release of Go 1.20 for bootstrap. ". 

Would you mind including this in an answer with your comment so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to install go1.20 or later, and use it:

```
gvm install go1.20
gvm use go1.20
```